# view content items on screen from front end with orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using orchard 1.6. I've created a content type 'ImageUpload' which has 2 fields 'Image' and 'Date'. So the user can select todays date and upload an image.  The uploads can be viewed from the 'Content Items' section of the dashboard but...

I would separately like to access/view the uploads from a different section(as the user wont have access to view the content items page) Iv set up a navigation menu but how can I view the records?

The content items are stored in the 'ContentItemVersionRecord' table...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. View the content items on the front end? Try using the projections module. You create a query that gets content of ImageUpload type and then you create a projection page that will use this query. Enable Projections feature, it comes with 1.6